# How do I make a multiple file upload?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a multiple image uploader. The file upload fields are being added in the form dynamically using jquery. I tried making an array of the fields since I don't want to have a hidden field. so my generated upload fields look like

```
<input type="file" id="img0" name="img[]"/>
<input type="file" id="img1" name="img[]"/>
<input type="file" id="img2" name="img[]"/>
.....
..
```

And on the php side I did something like

```
if(isset($_FILES['img']))
{
    foreach($_FILES['img'] as $k=>$v)
    {
        if($v!="")
        {
            uploadImage($k,0,0,0,"content/gallery/");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I know I am way too wrong, since in that code I am looping through the 'img' file's properties instead of all images....but I have no idea how to fix this.

PS: `uploadImage` is a function I wrote which expects the file input field's name as the first parameter.

Comment: post your uploadImage function

Comment: Did you use `<pre><?php var_export($_FILES); ?></pre>` to figure out how the $_FILES array is structured?

Comment: just make it not `img[]` but `img1, img2` and so on

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload the multiple files using php upload function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242249/how-to-upload-the-multiple-files-using-php-upload-function)

Comment: @John Conde, No that is a entirely different post by some other person, it has nothing to do with this one

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but the structure of $_FILES is not really intuitive and kind of backwards from what one might expect. To send the names of the uploaded files to your function, do this:

```
if (isset($_FILES['img']))  {
    print_r($_FILES)  // Just to see the $_FILES array's structure (testing only)
    foreach ($_FILES['img']['name'] as $k => $v)  {        // 'name' is an array
        if ($v != '')  {                                   // Each value of $v is a file name
            uploadImage($v, 0, 0, 0, 'content/gallery/');  // Change $k in your code to $v
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$rtn = array();
foreach ($_FILES['img'] as $key=>$val)
{
  foreach ($val as $fkey=>$fval)
  {
    $rtn[$fkey][$key] = $fval;
  }
}
print_r($rtn);
```

Answer (score 0):

One better option I can suggest -

jquery File Upload Plugin
Demo URL - http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/
Source Code - https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use unique names instead and just loops through $_FILES instead? I'm assuming you don't post any other files...

Otherwise, try a regular for() loop with index instead, since you are iterating over the file-objects properties. Also, you are passing the $key into the upload function, not the $value, I'm guessing that's one obvious mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you do something like:

```
$target_path = 'uploads/';

foreach($_FILES as $file) {
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $file['name']); 

    if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo 'The file '.  basename( $file['name']). ' has been uploaded';
    } else{
         echo 'There was an error uploading the file, please try again!';
    }
}
```

Just to be sure:

Don't forget to add enctype="multipart/form-data" to you form.

Comment: I think your missing the associate key (not me award you the down vote)

Comment: I'm guessing some idiot is downvoting everything that doesn't fix the problem, even though they are valid points. I gave the same suggestion as you to just iterate through $_FILES because he/she probably doesn't post other files that shouldn't be processed and got downvoted as well without explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Well at last I used hidden input field to pass the total number of images being uploaded, and uploaded them using their names

yeh I gave up on using arrays.....This array approach was a lot more work than it's worth.

Comment: I disagree, you'll only end up with more work by hacking around it. It's easy once you understand the $_FILES array structure.